# Could anyone help me to fix this error "ParseError: "Record does not exist or has been deleted."

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9

I have inherited the res.partner model because i need all the features of res.partner that's why i inherited the res.partner model in my custom module.I assure that i got all the features what i presume before.But the problem is when my module is installed while i can't able to install some other modules. If i try to install like point of sale while the server raise the error.The error is: "Record does not exist or has been deleted."

python code:

```
 class Residents(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'res.partner'
     _name = "residents.detail"

     image = fields.Binary(default=lambda self: self._get_default_image())
     name = fields.Char(required=True)
```

xml code:

```
  <record id = "add_field_view_partner_form" model = "ir.ui.view">
       <field name = "name">add.fields</field>
       <field name = "model">residents.detail</field>
              <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
                      <form string = "residents">
                      <sheet>
                           <field name="image" widget='image' class="oe_avatar" options='{"preview_image": "image_medium", "size": [90, 90]}'/>

                           <field name="name" default_focus="1" placeholder="Name" />                               
                      </sheet>
                     </form>
               </field>
    </record >
```

Error:

```html
ParseError: "Record does not exist or has been deleted.
None" while parsing /home/sibi/odoo/workspace/odoo-9.0c-20170717/openerp/addons/auth_signup/auth_signup_data.xml:6, near

             < record id="default_template_user" model="res.users">
                <field name="name">Template User</field>
                <field name="login">portaltemplate</field>
                <field name="active" eval="False"/>
                <!-- Avoid auto-including this user in any default group, just like a typical portal member -->
                <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0,  [ref('base.group_portal')])]"/>
                <!-- allow signuped users to have a alias -->
                <field name="alias_name">_usertemplate</field>
            </record>
```

Comment: Are you able to install POS if you uninstall your custom module?

Comment: Thanks for your reply . after uninstalled my custom module if i try to install POS this error  has come " ParseError: "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "res_groups_name_uniq""

Comment: It seems that is saying the POS module is trying to create a Group, but a group already exists with the same name. Check the `data` files in the module, look for any with a model of `res.groups`, and ensure you don't have any with the same name.